# Need help configuring Grails with Oracle JDBC thin client Encryption

Tags: oracle, grails, encryption

I need to set up our Grails app with AES encryption going to Oracle. In all the Java examples I have seen you create a Properties object, create an OracleDataSource and call setProperties, like so:

```
OracleDriver dr = new OracleDriver();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty( OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL,AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
// set more
(OracleConnection)dr.connect(url,prop);
```

In Grails, connections are handled by DataSource.groovy, which is a BasicDataSource, and so although you can configure properties easily with a closure like the following:

```
myDatasource {
pooled = false
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
username = username
password = password
url =      url
logSql = true
format_sql = true
pooled = true
properties {
    maxActive = 8
    maxIdle = 4
    minIdle = 1
    initialSize = 1
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
    maxWait = 10000
    validationQuery = "select 1 from dual"
    testOnBorrow=true
    testWhileIdle=true
    testOnReturn=true
}
```

All of the properties in that closure correspond to setters for BasicDataSource, so you can't just shove the OracleConnection properties in there.

Has anyone found a way to set up Oracle encryption for Grails? I would appreciate any help you can give

Brian

Comment: What version of Grails?

Answer (score 1):

The datasource is configured from settings in `DataSource.groovy` but only if there isn't already a Spring bean configured, and it's easy to configure one yourself in `resources.groovy`.

One thing to be aware of is that although we use the `dataSource` bean, that's a proxy of the real bean (actually a proxy of a proxy - one to ensure that calls to `getConnection()` return the current connection used by an active transaction if one exists and another that avoids database initialization calls if a retrieved pooled connection doesn't end up being used for a query before being returned) so you should override the `dataSourceUnproxied` bean to retain the benefits of the proxies.

I don't have access to an Oracle instance to test this but it should be close to what you need:

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
import oracle.net.ano.AnoServices

beans = {

   def props = [
      (OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL): AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED,
      (OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES): '(' + AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES256 + ')',
      (OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL): AnoServices.ANO_REQUESTED,
      (OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_TYPES): '(' + AnoServices.CHECKSUM_SHA1 + ')']

   dataSourceUnproxied(OracleDataSource) {
      connectionProperties = props as Properties
      implicitCachingEnabled = true
      password = '...'
      delegate.URL = '...' // can't use URL = '...' because of Groovy's default import of java.net.URL
      user = '...'
   }
}
```

Depending on the version of the driver the property names might be different (e.g. `properties` instead of `connectionProperties`, `cachingEnabled` instead of `implicitCachingEnabled`, etc.) and you can set additional properties as needed corresponding to the various setter methods available, e.g. `fastConnectionFailoverEnabled = true` for `setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true)`.

Depending on the version of Grails the configured `dataSource` is probably a Tomcat JDBC `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` and not a commons-dbcp `BasicDataSource`; the change was made [for Grails 2.3](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/7087) and earlier versions can (and should because of its significantly better performance) use the [jdbc-pool](https://grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool) plugin.

I looked at the source of the Tomcat JDBC driver wondering if it could/should be used as the real DataSource impl and letting it call `getConnection()` on the Oracle driver and saw that it supports a `connectionProperties` property that might make this simpler. It might be possible to concatenate the encryption properties in the supported format and add that to

```
dataSource {
   driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
   username = '...'
   ...
   connectionProperties = 'oracle.net.encryption_types_client=(AES256);' +
                          'oracle.net.encryption_client=REQUIRED;' +
                          'oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUESTED;' +
                          'oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=(SHA1)'
}
```

Check out the [Tomcat JDBC Pool docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) for more info.